# как сделать удобную панель задач в Linux?

Tags: linux, windows, desktop

Во время разработки необходимо постоянно переключатся между окнами терминалов. то сервер остановить, то выполнить какую  то команду, то паралельно с этим лог начать смотреть. 
Обычно я использую 2-3 окна одновременно. В основном я работаю в win10. 
В ней я делаю так:
 нажимаю на терминал в таскбаре и сверху вылазят превьюшки моих терминалов(если их там меньше 10 правда)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Они никогда не меняют порядок и я знаю что в первом у меня рансервер, во втором лог, в третьем я выполняю команды, а четвертый терминал выполняет роль скринсейвера.

Но из за некоторых ограничений OS, все же приходится часть работы делать в линуксе. 
Я знаю что в лине нормальных DE нет от слова совсем, то альт таб какой то мудреный(gnome3), то таск бара нет, то кнопки управления окном не с той стороны, а то все это сразу. Вообщем ничего удобнее mate который  форк gnome2 Для linux я не нашел, в нем хотя бы какой никакой таск бар есть, хотя если честно уровня win95

Но блин если я хочу переключится на другой терминал я должен альттабом выбирать нужный мне терминал среди микроскопических превьюх, какие еще и каждый раз меняют порядок.
при нажатии на терминал в таск баре открывается последний запущенный о.О

**вот что я пробовал:**

1. unity в ubuntu - просто полнейшая дичь
2. gnome2,mate - устаревшая шляпа
3. gnome3 - нестабильная поделка, из коробки нет почти ничего.
   полностью зависит от совести сторонних  разработчиков JS плагинов.
   для работы годится менее чем полностью
4. lxde,xfce  И прочие аббревиатуры под какими скрывается очередной
   бесполезный легковесный DE
5. kde - с выходом плазмы можно рассматривать как вариант, правда
   только в эстетическом плане, а так то в плане юзабилити он от
   конкурентов не далеко ушел

подскажите может я что пропустил, и там уже наконец выпустили нормальный linux DE для людей?

Comment: Как для вас удобно переключаться между окнами (именно от этого будет зависеть подходящая оболочка)? Может, стоит завести пять [виртуальных рабочих столов](https://geektimes.ru/post/128133/) (один свободный и четыре на упомянутые вами консоли) и благодаря этому переключаться на любую консоль сочетанием клавиш?

Comment: И ещё, что вы понимаете под «нормальной DE для людей» (каковы ваши требования к ней)?

Comment: А Вы не пробовали запустить один терминал xfce (и гномовый тоже вроде умеет, и kde-шный тоже умеет табы) и в нем открыть несколько табов, а уже в них переключаться с помощью ALT+1 ... ALT+N? Конечно, терминалы надо еще немного настроить, чтоб совсем удобно было (там некоторые сочетания клавиш для себя захомячены, которые нужны в mc). А вообще, ничего удобнее xfce пока не встречал. Виндовые рабочие столы и рядом не валялись. Просто надо под себя немного настроить. От цветовых схем, до положения заголовков/системных кнопок.

Comment: @Vladimir, поддерживаю. А ещё есть `tmux`. Это я уже для ОП говорю.

Comment: чтоб переключатся по ALT+* нужно еще открыть какой то терминал, а для этого еще найти где он там среди 45 окон. Если кто не понял я не сижу только в консоли, они только как вспомогательный элемент. Виндовые рабочие столы это какие? они появились только в вин10, не вижу в них никаких проблем. хотя и пользы особой тоже

Comment: я не использую табы в терминале,у меня монитор больше чем 3 дюйма,так что там можно уместить много терминалов рядом и переключатся бессмысленно

Comment: 1. на представленном скриншоте показаны исключительно терминалы. мы не обязаны обладать умением читать мысли вопрошающего. 2. в перечисленных мной DE есть виртуальные рабочие столы, доступные обычно по сочетаниям Ctrl+F1.. F-12 (или можно настроить). Это легко решает проблему расположения 100500 окон других прог. 3. В виндах есть только один родной рабочий стол - explorer aka проводник aka "рабочий стол". И он- почти предел неудобства. Да, в вин10, наконец, появилось подобие виртуальных рабочих столов. вроде бы. сам не видел, только слышал/читал. всего лишь на около 30 лет позже юниксовых xD .

Comment: на 30 или 40 какая разница, не делали значит не надо было. собственно я и сейчас не наблюдаю тотального использования рабочих столов рядовыми пользователями.

Comment: Судя по описанию вам нужен tiled window manager, например, **awesome**.

Comment: ставишь на гном3 dash-to-dock и windowoverlay-icons и очень удобно держать много окон.

Comment: @JohnDoe, не стоит равняться на рядовых пользователей. Они и горячие клавиши не используют - только мышку. Но это не значит, что это правильный подход к работе с компьютером.

Comment: 0andriy, о да. давно мне его не советовали